# NPE using Google maps services on mapView.onCreate(...)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

### Background

Our app has access to Google Maps, and one of the fragments needs to show a map. Due to some limitations, we had to use MapView instead of MapFragment, as such:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout...., null);
    mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(...);
    //...
    return rootView;
}
```

### The problem

Using Crashlytics, we got a lot of crash reports on various devices and Android versions.

The crash shows this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.af.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.onTransact(SourceFile:66)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzzW(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at ...
```

Here is what Crashlytics told me about the devices and Android versions:

Android versions: 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.4.2, 5.0, 5.0.2, 5.1, 6.0, 6.0.1.

Devices:

- Huawei: G610 U30, G6 U10, Ascent G510
- Wiko: Lenny, Rainbow Jam, Highway signs
- ZTE: Staraddict II plus, Z740G, ZTE blade III

and others

### What I've tried

I've tried searching for the issue, and only similar one I've found is this:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021

However, I can't find a solution or a workaround for it, and I don't see when it's supposed to be fixed, and if it's really the same issue (because the description isn't the same).

### The question

Why does it occur?

Is there any way to fix it? Any workaround? Is the issue that I've found - really what I look for?

Comment: But why you used `MapView`?

Comment: Have you used `MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` and obtained Google map by using `getMapAsync()` method of the **MapView** ?

Comment: @MuchOverflow Yes. This was written this way on some tutorials. I've updated the question to show more of what is written in the code

Comment: @MD Because of multiple reasons. Some of them are : the fragment has more than just a map to show, and putting a fragment within a fragment might still cause weird issues. Also, it should be ok to use it, as even the samples have an example of using it (though it's different and is inside an activity instead: "RawMapViewDemoActivity.java" in here: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples )

Comment: The issue in the link you provided occurs in Google Play Services v8.4. If you are using it, it may be your issue. You could also try searching `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()` in your logcat to see. I think the reason why @MuchOverflow ask that is because you can omit `MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` because you always get a non-null value(GoogleMap) when using `getMapAsync()`. See [MapInitializer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer).

Comment: @gerardnimo So what's the fix for this? to remove the "MapsInitializer.initialize(...)" part?